# Social login Angular 4+ and Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

im having trouble understanding how to use Google as authentication provider in a Angular 4 + 
Spring boot application. I have followed this tutorial: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

Any by Springboot backend works fine:

When i type in my browser http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html i will be redirected to google to log in and my server will provide a token for the user.

Now in the next step i want to create angular client application. I have a homepage with a button to log in. From what i understand, on click i should redirect user to link like: **host/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=host/homepage**.

How can i redirect user from withing my angular application to external site on button click?

```
  <button (click)="login()" class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">
Login with Google
  </button>
```

login component:

```
export class LoginComponent  {

  constructor() { }

  login() {
  }

}
```